How best to translate "the tip of the iceberg"?
I was listening to a podcast and heard the speaker refer to something as "le sommet de l'iceberg," which surprised me because I hadn't heard that before. When I went to look up translations of "the tip of the iceberg," what I found instead was "la partie visible de l'iceberg" or "la partie émergée de l'iceberg," both of which sound extremely unidiomatic to an English speaker's ears - "the visible part of the iceberg" (LOL). I also saw "la pointe de l'iceberg."
Which of these is actually the most modern/common/idiomatic? Is there not a single well-established idiom for this in French as there is in English, where you would never really say anything except "the tip"?

"Somment de l'iceberg" sonne un peu étrange (même si on comprend), car un iceberg est généralement vu comme applati au dessus (sorte de plateau de glace), donc il n'a pas vraiment de sommet.

Et il peut également avoir des sommets (géométriquement parlant) immergés (même si le sens plus courant du mot "sommet" implique la position "en haut".)

What I found instead was "la partie visible de l'iceberg" or "la partie émergée de l'iceberg," both of which sound extremely unidiomatic to an English speaker's ears.
Idiomaticity in one language (by definition!) doesn't imply idiomaticity in another language, so both partie émergée and partie visible are indeed the most common expressions used in French.
Anyway, pointe, closer to 'tip', can be heard along with sommet and haut.


"Idiomaticity in one language doesn't imply idiomaticity in another language" I know, I know, but sometimes something just sounds so circuitous that it's hard to believe it could be the common way of saying something.

@ninja米étoilé Or rather just as descendre à quatre pattes seems circuitous compared to climb down – which, after all, is not at all the same as just descendre. But yes, there are lots of examples of things being simple and idiomatic in one language and not in another. English speakers are frequently shocked that the Mandarin for ‘siblings’ is literally ‘big-brothers little-brothers big-sisters little-sisters’, but it works fine in Mandarin; conversely, Faroese people are baffled that the English require a mouthful like tenosynovitis to express the simple notion of gø.

"descendre à quatre pattes" isn't "climb down", lol. It's literally "4 legs" and the internet says it's "scramble down".
"The legionnaires scrambled down the ravine and up the other side, without returning fire. "

@ninja米étoilé My somewhat facetious point was that climbing down the stairs is not the same thing as going down the stairs. Going down is neutral as to how you move (just like descendre is), whereas climbing down denotes that you have to use your hands to steady yourself in the descent – for example if you’re going down very steep stairs or a loose and craggy hill, or if you’re very drunk.

@Engineer À quatre pattes is more literal and stronger than climb down, that’s true – it’s more equivalent to ‘on all fours’ (using your hands not just to steady yourself, but to support your weight the same as your feet/knees). Scramble down is not the same either, though – it means you’re using your hands to steady yourself, but with an added notion that you’re moving hurriedly or awkwardly. In your example, the legionnaires aren’t necessarily crawling on all fours, but they are hurrying across uneven terrain to avoid enemy fire.

The common phrase is "la partie émergée de l'iceberg" (in opposition to "la partie immergée")

To answer the question directly: No, French does not have a single well-established idiom for ‘the tip of the iceberg’. What I hear people say (in France) is:

“la pointe de l'iceberg” and
“le sommet de l'iceberg”

but in written texts the most common expressions appear to be:

“la partie visible de l'iceberg” and
“la partie émergée de l'iceberg”

Several others are in relatively widespread use. A common error is to write “la partie immergée de l'iceberg”, which of course has the opposite meaning and should only be used if you actually intend to refer to the submerged part.

"La pointe de l'iceberg" is, however, used both for the tip and for the bottom of the iceberg.
